# Apply search on Kendo UI grid with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

I am using **KendoUI** for my current application with **AngularJS**. I want to add custom search feature on **KendoUI** Grid control. For that i have placed a TextBox above the kendo-grid. Now i want to apply search on button click. Can you suggest me how we can refrech that kendoUI grid dataSource and filter according to search criteria.

Thanks
RAVI MITTAL

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented a similar feature before. What I did was the following:

First I added a filter field on the grid's toolbar:

```
$("#gridPortfolio").kendoGrid({
....
toolbar: 
 [
 ...
   {name: "filter", 
    template: "<div> <input class='k-textbox k-space-right' id='FieldFilter' type='text' placeholder='NIT' disabled />\
                   <span class='k-icon k-i-search'></span>\
               </div>" },
 ],
...
});
```

Then I bound the keyup event on the combobox to a function like so:

```
$("#FieldFilter").keyup(function () {
            portfolioGridFilter();
        });
```

And finally I modified and applied the filters on the grid in that function:

```
portfolioGridFilter: function () {

        var portfolioFilters = new Array();

        var searchText = $("#FieldFilter").val();

        if (searchText.length >= 3) {
            portfolioFilters.push({ field: "Field", operator: "contains", value: searchText });
        }

        if (portfolioFilters.length >= 1) {
            _yourGridsDataSource.filter(portfolioFilters);
        }

        if (searchText.length == 0) {
            _yourGridsDataSource.filter([]);
        }

    },
```

Comment: Well as i am using AngularJS with KendoUI so i cannotuse that sample of code but i got the idea. Thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

This kendo example should get you on the right track:
[Grid with Toobar](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/AngularJS/toolbar-template-with-angular)